# Django settings module and relative paths

Tags: python, django

Below is a part of my directory structure. I am keeping settings in a separate folder for keeping them different for produvtion and development.

```
DjangoApp
  templates/
    base.html
  OtherApp/
  DjangoApp/
   manage.py
   __init__.py
   settings/
    __init__.py
    base.py
    local.py
    test.py
    production.py
```

Below are the template settings in my base.py setting file.

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

It searches for the templates directory inside the settings folder. How to resolve this?

Comment: show your directory tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `dirname` three times:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname
PROJECT_PATH = dirname(dirname(dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

---

- `dirname(...)`: `../DjangoApp/DjangoApp/settings`
- `dirname(dirname(...))`: `../DjangoApp/DjangoApp`
- `dirname(dirname(dirname(...)))`: `../DjangoApp`